# How to plot $\frac{x^{-2/3} e^ { \left(-\frac{x^{2/3}}{2}\right)}}{\sqrt{2 \pi 9}}$ for negative real numbers?

Tags: plotting

While trying to  $\text{Plot}\left[\frac{x^{-2/3} e^ {
 \left(-\frac{x^{2/3}}{2}\right)}}{\sqrt{2 \pi  9}},\{x,-5,5\}\right]$ in mathematica, I was initially wondered (though mathematica's silence was rationale) that it was not plotted for negative values of $x$.

`Plot[1/Sqrt[2*Pi*9]*Exp[-(x^(2/3)/2)]*x^(-2/3), {x, -5, 5}]`

After spending a day of struggling to understand the reason, I finally understood the problem - complex roots of power terms involved in above equation.

Though, I was interested in real output only (real solutions only), how to plot the above equation (which is even function from real space to real space) in matematica.

I did try, taking the absolute value of the function above but that didn't work either.

**What should be easiest way to let the mathematica know that we are only interested in real output only?**

Any suggestions please !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[1/Sqrt[2*Pi*9]*Exp[-(x^2)^(1/3)/2] (x^(-2))^(1/3), {x, -5, 5}]
```